# What is more quicker is seconds ans precise provider : GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER if both are enabled?

Tags: android

I need to find location with android. My question is what is more quicker is seconds ans precise provider : GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER if both are enabled ? Can you tell me how long it takes to return location, I am new to this stuff and don't have any idea about time .

Comment: many matching questions with beautifull answers are there... just search a bit on SO...

Answer (score 1):

You can select the [Criteria](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html) yo want to get the best provider, like for example if your criteria is precision:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria c = new Criteria();
c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
final String PROVIDER = lm.getBestProvider(c, true);
```

Also if you want quick location, you can get the last known location with a function like this (Extracted from [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html)):

```
public static Location getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager locationManager)
{
    Location bestResult = null;
    float bestAccuracy = 0;
    long bestTime = 0;

    List<String> matchingProviders = locationManager.getAllProviders();

    for (String provider: matchingProviders) {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
            long time = location.getTime();

            if ((time > minTime && accuracy < bestAccuracy)) {
                bestResult = location;
                bestAccuracy = accuracy;
                bestTime = time;
            }
            else if (time < minTime && 
                    bestAccuracy == Float.MAX_VALUE && time > bestTime){
                bestResult = location;
                bestTime = time;
            }
        }
    }

    return bestResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, GPS_PROVIDER, takes more time than NETWORK_PROVIDER considering that you are requesting for a new location. NETWORK_PROVIDER is generally quick, but GPS_PROVIDER , i can't tell you(i don't know) the exact time for this.

GPS is accurate over NETWORK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i found that NETWORK_PROVIDER is quicker than GPS_PROVIDER , It is difficult to say that
"how long it takes to return location" it's not same always...

Check this ,which i am using for retrieving the current location :

http://code.google.com/p/messesinfoandroid/source/browse/trunk/src/cef/messesinfo/maps/MyLocation.java?spec=svn12&r=12

Answer (score 0):

GPS => More accurate, more time needed
Network => Less accurate, less time needed

(And, of course, you can define your preferences about this with the object Criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Also GPS provider works only outdoors, Network provider works indoors as well.

Comment: To improve this answer, consider adding a link to a reference or documentation

Comment: Sure Jonathan, inside usually means in a building - reinforced concrete ar cement walls, which are unpenetratable for the hi freq. GPS signals. But inside a woodden house, GPS will work just like outside.